# How to set default functionality to all text boxes in one form

Tags: jquery, html, jsf

I did my research online and did not find appropriate answer.

```
<ui:define>
    <h:form id="formName"> 
        <h:inputText id="p1"/>
        <h:inputText id="p2"/>
        <h:inputText id="p3"/>
        <h:inputText id="p4"/>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="javascripts">      
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(document).on('opened','[data-reveal]',function() {
            $("#formName input:text").on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
                var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (code == 13) {                                                                       
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }); 
        }
```

My question is for all these input text from id p1 to p4 , I have to disable enter key. Instead of writing KeyPress events for each of these Id's, how to make it neat code?

Comment: Aside from the missing closing bracket your code looks fine. You could arguably remove the `return false;` and just leave the `preventDefault()`. Do you have a specific issue with it?

Comment: When I write logs for testing, it is not even going in that keyup or keypress function. I think they way I am trying to access those input text is wrong.

Comment: where is this `opened` event being triggered? And is it being triggered? Does form exist when it is triggered? Not much information provided here

Comment: That is been triggered on page load.

Comment: @ashlesha can you try `$('#formName').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code == 13) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});`?

Comment: you can also try `$("form :input").on("keypress", function(e) {
    return e.keyCode != 13;
});` check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bcjLxpzs/

Comment: @Sushil , this is disabling enter key on all the fields in the form. I want in specific to h:inputText only

Comment: try the fiddle option then

Comment: great @ashlesha. let me post this as a solution then. please upvote it and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: posted my solution @ashlesha. please upvote it and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86634/discussion-between-sushil-and-ashlesha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code to disable `form submit` on `enter` key for `input` fields

***EDIT***

as suggested by @dognose, you should use `keyup` or `keydown` as `keypress` may not be supported by all the browsers.

```
$("form :input").on("keyup keydown keypress", function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    return e.keyCode != 13;
});
```

check this updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bcjLxpzs/1/)**. hope this helps.

Comment: You should use `keydown` or `keyup`. `keypress` is not triggered for control keys in various browsers, which might lead to unexpected results.

Comment: thanks @dognose. let me edit my answer.

Comment: Some information on this: http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events *Keydown triggers on any key press and gives scan-code. Keypress triggers after keydown and gives char-code, but it is guaranteed for character keys only.*

Comment: updated my answer. thanks for the info @dognose.

Comment: thanks @ashlesha. glad was able to help you.